# How to convert UTC date and time format to zone time format?

Tags: java, datetime, formatting

I have a method which generates a random date and time.

```java
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.Period;

public String getRandomFormattedDateAndTime() {
    LocalDateTime date = generateRandomDateAndTimeInPast();
    return formatDate(date);
}
        
public LocalDateTime generateRandomDateAndTimeInPast() {
    return LocalDateTime.now()
                        .minus(Period.ofDays(
                            (new Random().nextInt(365 * 2))
                        ));
}

  public static String formatDate(LocalDateTime date) {
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT_PATTERN);
    return dateTimeFormatter.format(date);
  }
```

and the printed output is something like `"2020-08-07T08:57:09Z"`

However, i need to obtain the same value with time zone format `2020-08-07T10:57:09+02:00`  which has the `+02:00` (my local time).

I have seen several questions and pages [like this](https://mkyong.com/java/java-convert-date-and-time-between-timezone/), but they do not give me a clue.

Comment: can't you use `ZonedDateTime`?

Comment: No, i need the `LocalDateTime `

Comment: `LocalDateTime` not have Zone part!

Comment: I don't think you (only) need the `LocalDateTime` because it won't store any information about zone or offset and simply adding the literal `'Z'` is not a good workaround. By the way, why a `SimpleDateFormat` when there's a `DateTimeFormatter` in `java.time.format`?

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:m:ssZ").format(date.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()))`  or similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not provided the code of your method, `formatDate(LocalDate)`. However, you have mentioned that `String getRandomFormattedDateAndTime()` is returning you `2020-08-07T08:57:09Z`. The following method, `getDateTimeInMyTz(String)` provides you with what you are looking for:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(getDateTimeInMyTz("2020-08-07T08:57:09Z"));
    }

    public static String getDateTimeInMyTz(String strDtUtc) {
        Instant instant = Instant.parse(strDtUtc);
        ZoneOffset offset = ZoneId.systemDefault().getRules().getOffset(instant);
        return instant.atOffset(offset).toString();
    }
}
```

**Output in my timezone which has an offset of `+01:00` hours:**

```
2020-08-07T09:57:09+01:00
```

**Usage:** Replace `getDateTimeInMyTz("2020-08-07T08:57:09Z")` with `getDateTimeInMyTz(getRandomFormattedDateAndTime())`.

If you share the code of your method, `formatDate(LocalDate)`, I can suggest further simplification.

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: I added the code of the `formatDate()`, but your answer already worked well for me. But, i am still interested to the potential improvments.

Comment: @Jeff - I am glad the solution worked for you as I expected. I can see that now you have posted the code of `formatDate` but in order to analyze the potential improvement, I need to know the value of `DATE_TIME_FORMAT_PATTERN`. By the way, I can see that you have imported `SimpleDateFormat`. I suggest you do not use `SimpleDateFormat` as it is error-prone. `DateTimeFormatter` can do all that what `SimpleDateFormat` can do, in a cleaner way.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
ZonedDateTime  zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now().minus(Period.ofDays((new Random().nextInt(365 * 2))));
System.out.println("Date Time:" + zonedDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
```

**Output**: Date Time:2019-07-13T14:27:51.909+05:30

Note: 05:30 is my time zone (local) offset

Comment: @OleV.V. thanks. I updated the code accordingly so it won't create confusion.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you're using the type `LocalDateTime`. LocalDateTime can't be formatted with timezone pattern as it doesn't contains any timezone information...

Switch to `ZonedDateTime` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why people are involving `ZonedDateTime` here, but it seems to be a valid approach...

However, I want to add another one, that is the use of an `OffsetDateTime`.

This is an adjusted version of your method `generateRandomDateAndTimeInPast`:

```java
public static OffsetDateTime generateRandomDateAndTimeInPast(int offset) {
    return OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.ofHours(offset))
                        .minusDays(
                            ThreadLocalRandom.current()
                                            .nextInt(365 * 2)
                        );
}
```

An example use could look like this, please note the implicit call to `OffsetDateTime.toString()` by directly `System.out`ing the instance of `OffsetDateTime`. You can alter the output by calling `OffsetDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter)`.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    OffsetDateTime odt = generateRandomDateAndTimeInPast(2);
    System.out.println(odt);
}
```

This prints out datetimes formatted like the following (randomly generated) one:

```
2020-10-14T10:44:23.304+02:00
```

If you need a `LocalDateTime` (that won't contain or print any offset), you can simply get it from the `OffsetDateTime` like this:

```java
LocalDateTime ldt = odt.toLocalDateTime();
```

A `ZonedDateTime` has that method, too, so if you use that or an `OffsetDateTime` you can always have the `LocalDateTime` they are based on by calling `toLocalDateTime()`.

Comment: @user15793316 Good point... I read this comment but could not imagine a way that prints out a `LocalDateTime` with an offset that is not hard-coded in some pattern. But I will edit the answer a little to include getting a `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: Yes, @user15793316, that comment contains a handy way to achieve something that appears desired, but I am not quite sure if OP's explanations are sufficient.